# CSS and jQuery - how to force 2 rules to work together

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a html table.
I need 2 rules to work:

1. On mouse over table row should change background color.
2. Cells in 1 column should be with different color depending on cell content, for example - if value in the cell="Green" , background should be green.

For the first rule I did rule in css:

```
tr:hover
{
    background: brown;
}
```

For the second - I've attached jQuery 2.0.3 and added js function which create class "color" for td:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('td.color').each(function(){  
    var x = $(this).text().trim();
    if ( x === "Green" ) $(this).css({background: 'green'});
    else if (x === "Yellow") $(this).css({background: 'yellow'}) ;
    else if (x === "Red") $(this).css({background: 'red'}) ;
    });

 });
```

The html of table is:

```
<table>
    <tr  class='tr'>
        <td class='td'>Name1</td>
        <td class='td'>Green</td>
        <td class='color'>Green</td>
    </tr>
     <tr  class='tr'> 
         <td class='td'>Name2</td>
         <td class='td'>Yellow</td>
         <td class='color'>Yellow</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='tr'>
        <td class='td'>Name3</td>
        <td class='td'>Red</td>
        <td class='color'>Red</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

(class color assigned only to last column)

The sample with result you can see here: **http://jsfiddle.net/bM5aW/7/**

So, backgrounds in last column are coloured depending on text value, and table rows change background color on mouse over event.
 **But** the last column doesn't change color on mouse over, as I understand because "**td**" rule from js script overrides "**tr**" rule from css.
 How to force "tr" rule to work if "td" rule was also declared?

Comment: Why are there "tr" and "td" classes assigned to every <tr> and <td> element? Seems redundant...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a !important to the rule

```
tr:hover, tr:hover td {
    background: brown !important;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/B8mMY/)

The problem is you are applying an inline style to the last td element, which has precedence over the `tr` element's style.

---

Another option is to use class selectors to apply the color

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('td.color').addClass(function(){
        return $.trim($(this).text()).toLowerCase()
    })
});
```

then

```
tr:hover, tr:hover td {
    background: brown;
}
td.green {
    background: green;
}
td.yellow {
    background: yellow;
}
td.red {
    background: red;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dNREP/)

Comment: Great! Thank for quick response. Working sample is here: http://jsfiddle.net/bM5aW/8/

Comment: @Vladimir I had commented for using specific selectors but Arun is right, you are using inline styles as you are targeting the elements using jQuery.. it is better to take a look at `nth-` CSS, if your text is going to be static, you won't require to call classes for each

Comment: The second variant is good when property has the same name as text inside cell. I think 1st variant is more flexible, isnt'it?

Answer (score 1):

Change the jQuery so it adds classes instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('td.color').each(function(){  
        var x = $(this).text().trim();
        if ( x === "Green" ) $(this).addClass("green");
        else if (x === "Yellow") $(this).addClass("yellow");
        else if (x === "Red") $(this).addClass("red");
    });   
 });
```

and add this to the CSS:

```
.green {
    background: green;
}

.yellow {
    background: yellow;
}

.red{
    background: red;
}


tr:hover td
{
    background: brown;
}
```